# why javax.annotation of different organization are different

Tags: java, jetty, guava

I'm using guava and jetty in my java project, while i found an odd problem.
In guava,it depend javax.annotation has so many class while in jetty the javax.annotation has less than in guava. What's the difference between them.

What's more,the javax.annotation in jetty is signed,while in guava is not signed. When the jvm load the class from the package javax.annotation in guava.jar and jetty.jar,it throw the SecurityException cause one package is signed and the others is not signed.

So,what's the real difference of the javax.annotation package between the guava.jar and the jetty.jar.

The package in guava:
[no sign and has lot of class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY2qt.pngclass)

The package in jetty:
[signed and has little class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkT4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different libraries that provide types in the `javax.annotations` package. The one Guava is using is a JAR from the (now abandoned) [JSR-305 proposal](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305). In Maven this is [`com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.code.findbugs%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsr305%22).

The other JAR appears to be [`org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.annotation:1.1.0.v201108011116`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty.orbit%7Cjavax.annotation%7C1.1.0.v201108011116%7Corbit). It's not clear where that JAR comes from, and it appears to have been uploaded in 2011 and then never updated since.

The conflict between these two JARs appears to be [a well-known one](http://blog.anthavio.net/2013/11/how-many-javaxannotation-jars-is-out.html).

It appears that the "dependency" on this JAR was added in [Guava release 13](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release13), but the release notes for that version say:

> Made findbugs a provided dependency to avert dep conflicts when using findbugs 2.0. The side-effect of this change is that projects which relied upon Guava to grant access to the JSR-305 annotations "for free" will break unless they provide their own direct dependency on that jar (or an equivalent). Projects should always have been directly depending on JSR-305 (per maven best-practice), but this change makes that should into a must.

Because of this, from what I understand, Guava doesn't actually have any dependency on the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9` JAR. So you should be free to exclude that dependency and provide your own `javax.annotations` JAR that you use instead. Alternatively, if you prefer the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` JAR, you should exclude the `org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.annotation` dependency from your build. You can refer to the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for how to exclude the unwanted dependency.

Comment: Yeah,I use both of them. And they conflict. The one in the jetty is signed and the one in the guava not signed. When jvm load the class in both jar， throw SecurityException.

Comment: @user2687943: Your original question was "What's the difference between them [the two JARs]". I think I answered that clearly enough. However, it sounds like your question now is "how do I resolve this dependency conflict?" I've updated my answer to answer that question as well.

Comment: Thanks so much,I'd already fix the conflict. I exclude the org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.annotation. Thanks,tanks.....

Comment: if you see artifact with "orbit" and "eclipse", it refers to the Eclipse Foundation legal requirement for vetting all 3rd party (not developed in Eclipse) dependencies through their "orbit" system of checks, validations, and modifications to that artifact. (often being nothing more than a set of OSGi manifests and a signed artifact proving that the dependency is now approved for use within the Eclipse Foundation).

Comment: The link to [a well known one](http://blog.anthavio.net/2013/11/how-many-javaxannotation-jars-is-out.html] is broken. It should be https://blog.anthavio.dev/2013/11/how-many-javaxannotation-jars-is-out.html
SO won't allow a change as the update is less than 6 characters